# Strapi on server with subdomain - problem with admin panel

Tags: strapi

I have default Digital Ocean installation of strapi. I've changed api based hostname for my domain and I have this error:

```
this:main.f910bea6.chunk.js:13 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://api.myhostname.app/admin' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://999.999.999.999/admin/init'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Main site is displaying correctly. Problem is in admin panel.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {

# Listen HTTP
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    #listen 80;
    server_name api.myhostname.app;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/hostname.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/hostname.key;



# Proxy Config
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://strapi;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

and .env file:

```
NGINX_URL=https://api.myhostname.app
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET="best"
```

and config:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  url: env('NGINX_URL', ''),
  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET'),
    },
  },
});
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem. This required rebuilding admin panel, like that:

```
npm run build
```

Weird but works.